# Is there a reason Java reflection getMethod sometimes does not work?

Tags: java, reflection

I have some code using `reflection` which I would like to use to call a `setter` method. Below is my code :

```
Method getObjectMethod = entityClass.getMethod(GET_METHOD_NAME);
if (getObjectMethod != null){
     Object p = getObjectMethod.invoke(obj);
     Class<?> pClass = p.getClass();

     Method setMethod = null;
     Method[] methodList = pClass.getDeclaredMethods();
     for (Method met: methodList){
         if (met.getName().equals(SET_METHOD_NAME)) {
             setVersionMethod = met;
             break;
          }
     }

     if (setMethod != null){
          setMethod.invoke(p, "UPDATED BY REFLECTION5");
     }
```

This works fine. However when I try to replace the loop with:

```
setMethod = pClass.getDeclaredMethod(SET_METHOD_NAME);
```

or

```
setMethod = pClass.getMethod(SET_METHOD_NAME);
```

I get a NoSuchMethodException.

Any idea why?

Comment: Here's the javadoc of getDeclaredMethod(): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethod-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class...-. Read its signature carefully, as well as its documentation. It has the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume you have a class:

```
class Foo {
    void bar(int i) {}
    void bar(String s) {}
}
```

And call:

```
Method bar = Foo.class.getDeclaredMethod("bar");
```

Which method should be returned? There are two possible matches, the one accepting an `int` the other one accepting a `String`. Above would only work if you'd have a method like this (no arguments):

```
void bar() {}
```

This means that when you want to get a `Method` via reflection, `getDeclaredMethod()` forces you to pass the argument types of the method you want to get:

```
Method barInt = Foo.class.getDeclaredMethod("bar", int.class);
Method barString = Foo.class.getDeclaredMethod("bar", String.class);
```

In your case, what you probably want is this:

```
setMethod = pClass.getDeclaredMethod(SET_METHOD_NAME, String.class);
```

Comment: Very nice answer!

Comment: Thanks, sorry should have read docs rather than following an example. Agree it is a duplicate.

Comment: @gringogordo you're welcome. I suggest you to work in an IDE (I prefer IntelliJ IDEA) they almost always allow you to read the documentation in your editor. Which makes it very easy for you to see why the code is not working as expected.